# error Command failed with exit code 1. with react-native and yarn eslint

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint, linter

When I run `yarn run lint fileName`, it returns

```
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

What I've tried are `yarn install` and `yarn upgrade`. `npm install` is also done.
Oddly, ESLint itself is working so it can edit my file in spite of this error.
However, I would like to solve this error.

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^3.8.0",
    "@freakycoder/react-native-header-view": "^0.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "eslint-cli": "^1.1.1",
    "expo": "^37.0.12",
    "expo-facebook": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-google-sign-in": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~8.1.0",
    "google-auth-library": "^6.0.2",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-tableview-simple": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.2.3",
    "eslint": "^7.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0"
  }
}
```

This is my package.json.
I am not sure what is the problem. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there is a lint finding that throws an error. ESLint does this if the rule is set to `error` and not `warning`. See discussion at https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7933 for the issue in npm (yarn may have same problem)

The short version is that you have to either:

- fix all lint findings
- change the rules to throw `warning` instead of `error`
- force your command to exit with 0 (e.g. package.json has `"lint": "eslint app/;exit 0"`)

Answer (score -3):

While it's not recommended you can silence the exit code in both by adding the `--silent` flag.

For npm:

```
npm run lint /file/path --silent
```

For yarn:

```
yarn run --silent lint /file/path
```

Comment: the `--silent` flag just hides the npm output, not the exit code itself